# In JMeter Post Data Not Sent In Request When Certain Character Strings Are Included

Tags: jmeter, http-post, performance-testing, url-encoding, postdata

In a test plan that I am trying to execute, there is a step that includes a post request with post data. One of the parameters in the post data includes special characters. The parameter name is `'__RequestVerificationToken'`. When the parameter name is spelled correctly, the request is sent with no post data included. The request fails. However when the parameter is changed slightly, post data will be included with the request. Because the correct parameter names are not sent, the request also fails. Below is a list of parameter names that do and do not break the sending of post data.

Parameter names that do break the sending of post data:

```
'__RequestVerificationToken'
'__RRequestVerificationToken'
'**RequestVerificationToken'
```

Parameter names that do not break the sending of post data:

```
'__TRequestVerificationToken'
'RequestVerificationToken'
```

Is there anything that I can do have my parameter name sent correctly without dropping post data from the request?

Comment: Encode them maybe?

Comment: try adding "" to the parameter name.

Comment: @rachna bafna, adding "" does allow the post data to be sent, but the original recording doesn't include any "", so the response is an error because the parameter is not present

Comment: @Ivan Markovic, encoding and unencoding have the same behavior

Comment: @Justin is there any error that you see when you send '__RequestVerificationToken' in jmeter.log?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try encoding them using 2 options:

- In Http Request check the checkbox encode in the parameters table
- Use function [__urlencode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode)

Comment: Neither checking the checkbox or encoding with __urlencode resolves the issue. I am currently using JMeter 2.9. I am also sending a separate parameter named 'Password', that includes special characters, and does have the checkbox encode checked. Is there a back end encoding issue that could be causing the problem?

Comment: First try with JMeter 3.0, then investigate backend issue